# Comparing two different tables to check that a new process is inserting the same data as an older one

Tags: sql, oracle

Note that the code and tables being worked on here is confidential, so all tables shown are in a simplified form and do not use the real table or column names. The database involved is an Oracle database. Assume that I can't change any of the data in the tables mentioned below; I can only query it. (I can create other data structures, like views, if that would help.)

I have a new process being built that is expected to insert essentially the same data as an old process into a brand new table. The actual format of the data is completely different (which is the point of the new process), but it's easy enough to put them into a mutually-compatible format in a query, so for the purposes of this question you can assume that the tables have the same format as each other. The problem I am trying to solve is the best way of comparing the data that will have been inserted into the tables, to check whether the new process is missing any data the old process is inserting, or whether it's inserting any extra data that it shouldn't.

The purpose of each table is to record a log of actions made against certain items in an application. Assume that the two tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE OLD_ACTION_LOG (
  OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  CLIENT_ITEM_ID NUMBER(20),
  ACTION_TYPE_ID NUMBER(20),
  ACTION_TIME DATE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_OLD_ACTION_LOG_1 FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT_ITEM_ID) REFERENCES CLIENT_ITEM (CLIENT_ITEM_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_OLD_ACTION_LOG_2 FOREIGN KEY (ACTION_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ACTION_TYPE (ACTION_TYPE_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE NEW_ACTION_LOG (
  NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID NUMBER(20) PRIMARY KEY,
  CLIENT_ITEM_ID NUMBER(20),
  ACTION_TYPE_ID NUMBER(20),
  ACTION_TIME DATE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_NEW_ACTION_LOG_1 FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT_ITEM_ID) REFERENCES CLIENT_ITEM (CLIENT_ITEM_ID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_NEW_ACTION_LOG_2 FOREIGN KEY (ACTION_TYPE_ID) REFERENCES ACTION_TYPE (ACTION_TYPE_ID)
);
```

The old process and the new process are (theoretically) inserted into whenever an action is taken. CLIENT_ITEM refers to the items in the application that are being updated, and ACTION_TYPE refers to the different actions that can be taken by the user - the structure of these tables doesn't matter to this problem. Any action should insert the same CLIENT_ITEM_ID and ACTION_TYPE_ID into both tables. The OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID and NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID are not expected to correspond to each other in any way, and it is possible for the ACTION_TIME to be slightly different depending on how long the action takes.

So, a snippet of the contents of the tables side-by-side might look something like this:

```
OLD_ACTION_LOG                                                      NEW_ACTION_LOG

OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID CLIENT_ITEM_ID ACTION_TYPE_ID ACTION_TIME         NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID CLIENT_ITEM_ID ACTION_TYPE_ID ACTION_TIME
100000            49             100            2020-11-16 13:00:00 29000             49             100            2020-11-16 13:00:00
100001            49             100            2020-11-16 13:00:09 29001             49             100            2020-11-16 13:00:10
100002            50             25             2020-11-16 13:00:15 29002             50             25             2020-11-16 13:00:15
100003            50             25             2020-11-16 13:00:15 29005             50             25             2020-11-16 13:00:16
100004            50             25             2020-11-16 13:00:16 29006             50             25             2020-11-16 13:00:16
100005            72             26             2020-11-16 13:00:19
                                                                    29011             72             80             2020-11-16 13:00:20
98765             72             26             2020-11-16 13:02:34 29012             72             26             2020-11-16 13:02:34
```

The kind of solution I'm looking for would need to be able to try and work out:

- that OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID 100000 and NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID 29000 refer to the same action (should be easy enough as all data is the same)
- that OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID 100001 and NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID 29001 refer to the same action (despite the one second discrepancy between the two entries)
- that OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID 100002, 100003, 100004 and NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID 29002, 29005, 29006 refer to the same set of actions (despite the overlapping times and the jump in NEW_ACTION_LOG_IDs)
- that OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID 100005 and NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID 29011 don't have a clear equivalent in the other table (a human observer might assume they are the same action and that the new process is inserting the wrong ACTION_TYPE_ID - the solution I'm looking for should not make any assumptions about this and shouldn't pair these two up in any way, since the idea is to highlight incorrect entries)
- that OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID 98765 and NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID 29012 refer to the same action (despite the decrease in OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID)

To summarise, given the above data, I would be hoping for a solution that would only return OLD_ACTION_LOG_ID 100005 and NEW_ACTION_LOG_ID 29011, leaving all the other records out, as matches should have been found for each of them.

I'm perfectly aware there's unlikely to be a foolproof solution to this, due to the shakiness of the data (it would be a lot easier if we could assume the times were the same, or that the IDs were ordered, but unfortunately this isn't possible in the application I'm working with). I'm just looking for something that could highlight the differences with a near enough degree of accuracy that any remaining false positives could be eliminated by a human observer without having to dig through all of the more obviously correct cases. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**:

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to compare the two tables.

```sql
SELECT o.old_action_log_id,
       n.new_action_log_id,
       COALESCE( o.client_item_id, n.client_item_id ) AS client_item_id,
       COALESCE( o.action_type_id, n.action_type_id ) AS action_type_id,
       COALESCE( o.action_time, n.action_time ) AS action_time
FROM   old_log_action o
       FULL OUTER JOIN new_log_action n
       ON (   o.client_item_id = n.client_item.id
          AND o.action_type_id = n.action_type_id
          AND o.action_time    = n.action_time
          )
ORDER BY
       action_time,
       client_item_id,
       action_type_id
```

If they match then they will have both `new_action_log_id` and `old_action_log_id` and if they are present only in one table then they will only have one. This means that, if you only want the non-matching rows then you can filter for `NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT o.old_action_log_id,
       n.new_action_log_id,
       COALESCE( o.client_item_id, n.client_item_id ) AS client_item_id,
       COALESCE( o.action_type_id, n.action_type_id ) AS action_type_id,
       COALESCE( o.action_time, n.action_time ) AS action_time
FROM   old_log_action o
       FULL OUTER JOIN new_log_action n
       ON (   o.client_item_id = n.client_item.id
          AND o.action_type_id = n.action_type_id
          AND o.action_time    = n.action_time
          )
WHERE  o.old_action_log_id IS NULL
OR     n.new_action_log_id IN NULL
ORDER BY
       action_time,
       client_item_id,
       action_type_id
```

**Update**:

If you want values within a few seconds then:

```sql
SELECT o.old_action_log_id,
       n.new_action_log_id,
       COALESCE( o.client_item_id, n.client_item_id ) AS client_item_id,
       COALESCE( o.action_type_id, n.action_type_id ) AS action_type_id,
       o.action_time AS old_action_time,
       n.action_time AS new_action_time
FROM   old_log_action o
       FULL OUTER JOIN new_log_action n
       ON (   o.client_item_id = n.client_item.id
          AND o.action_type_id = n.action_type_id
          AND o.action_time    BETWEEN n.action_time - INTERVAL '2' SECOND
                               AND     n.action_time + INTERVAL '2' SECOND
          )
WHERE  o.old_action_log_id IS NULL
OR     n.new_action_log_id IN NULL
ORDER BY
       action_time,
       client_item_id,
       action_type_id
```

**Option 2**:

Another alternative, if you just want to find unmatched items (and don't want to display the `action_log_id`s) then you can use `MINUS`. This would give all the values that are in the `old_log_action` table that are not also in the `new_log_action` table (and if you want the values form the other table then swap the two `SELECT` statements around):

```sql
SELECT client_item_id, action_type_id, action_time
FROM   old_log_action
MINUS
SELECT client_item_id, action_type_id, action_time
FROM   new_log_action
```

Comment: This is pretty useful if the action_time is guaranteed to be the same. Unfortunately, as mentioned, it may sometimes be a second or so out, so I can't make that assumption.

Comment: @AnthonyMercer Updated the first query.